# How do I remove only the popular items from a purchase and keep the others?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How do I remove the popularst items from a purchase?

I would like to remove the most popular articles from my data frame.

I am already receiving the top 5 articles. Unfortunately, I don't know how to remove these from my individual purchases.

For example, a purchase contains one popular item and two regular items. After the clean up, the popular item should be removed and only two items should remain.

```
import pandas as pd
d = {'purchaseid': [0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 8, 9, 9, 9, 9],
         'itemid': [ 3, 8, 2, 10, 3, 10, 4, 12, 3, 12, 3, 4, 8, 6, 3, 0, 5, 12, 9, 9, 13, 1, 7, 11, 11]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

print(df.head(5))

print(df['itemid'].nunique())
gb = df.groupby("itemid").size().nlargest(n=5, keep="first")
print(gb) # gives me the popularst items with the count

   purchaseid  itemid
0           0       3
1           0       8
2           0       2
3           1      10
4           2       3

14
# the popularst items
itemid
3     5
12    3
4     2
8     2
9     2
```

What I want after clean up

```
   purchaseid  itemid
-           -       - # purchase 0 has only 2 instead of 3 purchases
0           0       8 
1           0       2
2           1      10
-           -       - # This line should be completely removed, this is only for illustration.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that *itemid* of most popular items are contained in the **index** of *gb*
(the left column in the listing of *the popularst items* in your data sample).
Values of *gb* (the right column) hold only information **how many rows**
contains *df* for items with particular *itemid*.

So to get "not popular" items, you should select rows where *itemid* is **not**
in *gb.index*. The most natural way to get this result is *boolean indexing*
based on just this criterion:

```
result = df[~df.itemid.isin(gb.index)]
```

The result is:

```
    purchaseid  itemid
2            0       2
3            1      10
5            2      10
13           5       6
15           6       0
16           6       5
20           8      13
21           9       1
22           9       7
23           9      11
24           9      11
```

Your expected result starts with:

```
0           0       8
```

(0 - *index*, 0 - *purchaseid* and 8 - *itemid*), but I think it is a mistake.
Note that *itemid == 8* is among 5 most polular items (there are 2 of them).